# How to create a Taskbar on multiple monitors?

Tags: c++, windows

I have three monitors and I want too create a taskbar on all three of them in C++ ?

Comment: Are you referring to the Windows taskbar? i.e. the bar that contains the Start Menu?

Comment: I was going to suggest synergy...but that's for different computers with different os's working together...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various solutions already available to do this; in the past I've used [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) but recently I have switched to [DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion) as it does a better job replicating the Windows 7 Taskbar.